# Compare JSON array and JSON object: Cannot convert Array to String error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to compare json value and based on that i want to update the existing value,for example, currently we have "value" : [r0] in json, i want to compare and if value : [r0] ,then update it to [r0,r1]  but iam hiting error that it cannot compare and there is a cast issue, could someone suggest what could be done

```
public void updateJsonParameter(string file)    
{
    try
    {

        var list = new List<string> { "joe", "test" };
        JArray array = new JArray(list);
        var jobject = JObject.Parse(file);
        var ringvalue = (string)jobject["properties"]["parameters"]["ringValue"]["value"];   // unable to case here and compare  
        jobject["properties"]["parameters"]["ringValue"]["value"] = array;          // able to update value but i want to update after comparing the existing values 
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobject);
    }
```

following is the json format

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "jayatestdefid",
    "description": "test assignment through API",
    "metadata": {
      "assignedBy": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/MGTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/test",
    "parameters": {
      "ringValue": {
        "value": ["r0"]
      }
    },
    "enforcementMode": "DoNotEnforce",
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that `"value"` is a `string`. Shouldn't you be casting it to an array (or accessing a specific index in the array if you want a single value)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, as Klaycon said in his answer, it's worth noting that your "value" is not a single string.  In json, whenever you see `[` and `]` then you have a collection, or an array, or a list.

When I work with json strings, I always like to be able to convert them into a strongly typed object. There is a very handy online tool I use all the time: http://json2csharp.com/

I took your json string that you provided and pasted it into that website. Here is that your object(s) look like when converted into c# classes:

```
public class RootObject // You can name this whatever you want
{
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string assignedBy { get; set; }
}

public class RingValue
{
    public List<string> value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public RingValue ringValue { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public string policyDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
    public string enforcementMode { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we can easily do the logic you need as follows:

```
// This is your json string, escaped and turned into a single string:
string file = "{  \"properties\": {    \"displayName\": \"jayatestdefid\",    \"description\": \"test assignment through API\",    \"metadata\": {      \"assignedBy\": \"xyz@gmail.com\"    },    \"policyDefinitionId\": \"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/MGTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/test\",    \"parameters\": {      \"ringValue\": {        \"value\": [\"r0\"]      }    },    \"enforcementMode\": \"DoNotEnforce\",    }}";

// Convert your json string into an instance of the RootObject class
RootObject jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(file);

// Get a list of all the "values"
List<string> values = jobject.properties.parameters.ringValue.value;

// Loop over your colleciton of "value" and do your logic
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; ++i)
{
    if (values[i] == "r0")
    {
        values[i] = "r0,r1";
    }
}

// And finally, turn your object back into a json string
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobject);
```

And this is the final result:

```
{ 
   "properties":{ 
      "displayName":"jayatestdefid",
      "description":"test assignment through API",
      "metadata":{ 
         "assignedBy":"xyz@gmail.com"
      },
      "policyDefinitionId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/MGTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/test",
      "parameters":{ 
         "ringValue":{ 
            "value":[ 
               "r0,r1"
            ]
         }
      },
      "enforcementMode":"DoNotEnforce"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jobject.properties.parameters.ringValue.value` is an array `["r0"]` with one element `"r0"`. If you want to check if it's an array with one element and that element is `"r0"`, do exactly that:

```
var ringvalue = jobject["properties"]["parameters"]["ringValue"]["value"];
if(ringvalue.length == 1 && ringvalue[0] == "r0")
  jobject["properties"]["parameters"]["ringValue"]["value"] = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the ringvalue (which is an `JArray`) using `JArray.DeepEquals` and then replace if the comparison returns true. For example,

```
var list = new List<string> { "joe", "test" };
JArray array = new JArray(list);
JArray valueToCompare = new JArray(new[]{"r0"});

var ringvalue = (JArray)jobject["properties"]["parameters"]["ringValue"]["value"];  

if(JArray.DeepEquals(ringvalue,valueToCompare))
{   
   jobject["properties"]["parameters"]["ringValue"]["value"] = array;         
}
```